# LIME in R on xgboost model with objective 'count:poisson'

Tags: r, xgboost, poisson, lime

I am trying to use LIME in R to explain an xgboost model with the objective 'count:poisson'. It seems to work just fine for the standard 'reg:linear'. Is there a way around this? The question was previously asked here, but with no accepted answers.

[Can the R version of lime explain xgboost models with count:poisson objective function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280345/can-the-r-version-of-lime-explain-xgboost-models-with-countpoisson-objective-fu)

```
require(dplyr)
require(xgboost)
require(lime)

#generate data
df_train <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(n = 1000),
  x2 = rnorm(n = 1000),
  x3 = rnorm(n = 1000)) %>%
  mutate(y = rpois(1000, pmax(0, x1 + 2*x2 - 0.5*x3)))
         
df_hold_out  <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(n = 5),
  x2 = rnorm(n = 5),
  x3 = rnorm(n = 5)) %>%
  mutate(y = rpois(5, pmax(0, x1 + 2*x2 - 0.5*x3)))


#set matrix
dmat <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(df_train[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")]), label = df_train[["y"]])

#train with linear objective
mod_linear <- xgboost(data = dmat, nrounds = 100, params = list(objective = "reg:linear"))
#train with poisson objective
mod_poisson <- xgboost(data = dmat, nrounds = 100, params = list(objective = "count:poisson"))


#explain linear model
explainer_linear <- lime(x = df_hold_out, model = mod_linear, n_bins = 5)
explanation_linear <- lime::explain(
  x = df_hold_out[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")],
  explainer = explainer_linear,
  n_permutations = 5000,
  dist_fun = "gower",
  kernel_width = .75,
  n_features = 10,
  feature_select = "highest_weights")
#plot
plot_features(explanation_linear)




#explain poisson model
explainer_poisson <- lime(x = df_hold_out, model = mod_poisson, n_bins = 5)
explanation_poisson <- lime::explain(
  x = df_hold_out[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")],
  explainer = explainer_poisson,
  n_permutations = 5000,
  dist_fun = "gower",
  kernel_width = .75,
  n_features = 10,
  feature_select = "highest_weights")
#plot
plot_features(explanation_poisson)
```

trying to run the explain function on the poisson explainer ultimately tosses this error

```
Error: Unsupported model type
```